# how to get Multidimensional Array from a php file and use it in C#?

Tags: c#

Very new to C#...

Now I want a Multidimensional Array from a php file and use it in my C# functions.

how can I get the Array using C# code?

The php code is something like this:

```
<?php
return [
    "k1" => [
        "k11" => "v11",
        "k12" => "v12",
        "k13" => "v13"
    ],
//    "k1_old" => [
//        "k11_old" => "v11_old",
//        "k12_old" => "v12_old",
//        "k13_old" => "v13_old"
//    ],
    "k2" => [
        "k21" => "v21",
        "k22" => "v22",
        "k23" => "v23"
    ],
    "k3" => [
        "k31" => "v31",
        "k32" => "v32",
        "k33" => "v33"
    ]
];
?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this rather than just writing the equivalent in C#?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the php file owned by others and changes several times a day. I can use the data, but can`t edit it.

Comment: Can you perhaps wrap the file with a PHP script to output the data as JSON? Then run the wrapper script to produce a JSON file and import that with C#.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks for your suggestions! One of the google results was similar to this, but I still wondering if there is a another solution here. If not, I may actually try it.

Comment: If you don't like that solution, the only options I see are either 1) find or write code to parse the file into a dictionary of dictionaries, or some other data structure in .NET. This seems fragile. The other is 2) Find a library to interpret and execute the PHP in .NET and return the results as .NET objects.

Answer (score -1):

The above example is not an array in classical sence, since you are using a key dictionary structure.

You could define an array of strings like:

```c#
string[] str = {"foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

You example above would equate to this anonymous object:

```c#
object o = 
{
  { k1 = { k11 = "v11", k12 = "v12", k13 = "v13" } },
  { k2 = { k21 = "v21", k22 = "v22", k23 = "v23" } },
  { k3 = { k31 = "v31", k32 = "v32", k13 = "v13" } }
}
```

A bit messy to say the least.

If your goal was to create two-dimensional string array, then it could have been done like so:

```c#
string[][] strArray = 
{
  { "v11", "v12", "v13" },
  { "v21", "v22", "v23" },
  { "v31", "v32", "v13" }
}
```

if you wanted to access the "v23" value, it could be done by getting the value from `strArray[1][2]`.

Comment: The example in the question is php code, and I am not looking for the way of how C# buid arrays. Thanks for your answer, but I dont think it is what I needed.

Comment: Ok. Then it is better to pass your object from PHP with `json_encode` and then work on it in C# by deserializing the JSON object. See more on Microsoft webpage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: [copy from above]Thanks for your suggestions! One of the google results was similar to this, but I still wondering if there is a another solution here. If not, I may actually try it.